# MongoDB Replace _id field with existing field Id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing mongo collection. Each object inside looks similar to this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "Id": 4321,
  ...
}
```

The `"Id"` field I have is unique to each object.

Is it possible to run a `db.collection.update` query in such a way as I can replace the "_id" field with the contents of "Id"?

i.e.

```
{
  "_id": 4321,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Which mongo version are you using? 
Is it a one time update?

Comment: @MrS.Sharma Version 4.0.10. Yes, It's a one time update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mongo version 4.0.10, the following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "_id":"$Id"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "Id":0
        }
    },
    {
        $out:"collection"
    }
])
```

Data set:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d557c5f7c780d119a01a6de"), "Id" : 4321 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d557c5f7c780d119a01a6df"), "Id" : 3412 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d557c5f7c780d119a01a6e0"), "Id" : 1234 }
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : 4321 }
{ "_id" : 3412 }
{ "_id" : 1234 }
```

We are performing the aggregation on 'collection' and replacing the old data with the output of aggregation.

Comment: Thanks! I was importing another database, once I got rid of the duplicate records this worked great :)